# Pycharm EDU Error Installing

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, pycharm

When I install it, gives the error

```
Unrecognised VM option Maxpermsize =350m  
Could not create the java virtual machine  
A fatal exception has occurred
```

And when I changed the vmoption file and removed the line

```
-XX:Maxpermasize=350m
```

It still shows some error

I have openjdk 9-internal

I have installed pycharm community

But am not being able to install pycharm EDU

Comment: You should add which Java version your are using (command `java -version`)

Comment: Openjdk version 9 internal

Answer (score 7):

Java 9 is still in development and does not have a stable release yet. Remove it and replace it with Java 8, probably the error will be gone then.

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-9*
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Comment: @Bharat If this answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey round check button on the left of it. Otherwise feel free to leave a comment if something is still unclear or not working as expected. You should also invest two minutes to take a [tour] of our site and learn how it works. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!